# Sorting by one column then the

Tags: grep, colors, sort, columns

Say I have a output file with following:

```
010513  08:04   ROUTER1   192.168.1.1   68.130.5.10  HIT(1)
010513  08:04   ROUTER1   172.168.1.1   28.130.5.10  HIT(1)
010513  08:04   ROUTER1   122.168.1.1   168.130.5.10  HIT(1)
010513  08:04   ROUTER1   192.168.1.1   18.130.5.10  HIT(1)
010513  08:04   ROUTER1   152.168.1.1   58.130.5.10  HIT(1)
010513  08:04   ROUTER1   142.168.1.1   10.130.5.10  HIT(1)
```

I'm trying to sort with the 4th column followed by 5th and having highlighted colors would work too, as my true output file has about 20 columns.  Tried using various grep | sort commands and having difficulty getting this to work without running my result file a few times.  I don't script so I am sure there is one out there but thought I would ask if there are a combo command/variables I can try.

Answer (score 3):

`sort -V -k 4,5` could be what you're looking for. If you grep that output with say an IP pattern it would color the IPs (`sort -V -k 4,5 < file | grep -E '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'`).